# Go doesn't seem to pass pointers how I think it is

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I have a Go program here I'm using to test out a pointer error I'm having in a much larger http service program.

I have a pointer of a struct I'm wanting to pass to a function to initialize it. Naturally because it's a pointer, I shouldn't have to return anything. It should modify it directly.

However, that's not what is happening here.

```
func main () {
   var thing *Thing
   ModifyThing(thing)
   fmt.Println(thing)
}

func ModifyThing (thing *Thing) {
   thing = NewThing()
}

func NewThing () *Thing {
   thing := Thing{}
   return &thing
}

/// Output: <nil>
```

If I use `NewThing()` on my `thing` directly, I'll get an initialized pointer. However this doesn't work when I pass the pointer to a function that calls the same method. Is the memory location of my `thing` not being passed how I'm expecting?

Comment: `thing = NewThing()` doesn't modify an existing object; *it creates a new one.*  You're assigning a new reference to a variable whose original reference is almost certainly being *passed by value.*  Therefore, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ModifyThing` doesn't actually modify `thing`. It overwrites its local variable `thing` with a new pointer to a new instance of `Thing`, so it has no impact on anything else. If it *actually modified* `thing` - say, `thing.field = newValue`, that would be reflected in the caller.

If you wanted to overwrite the whole value pointed to by the pointer, you could also do that, but you have to explicitly overwrite *the memory being pointed to* rather than the pointer itself:

```
*thing = Thing{}
```

Notice we *dereference* `*thing`, and overwrite its value with a new `Thing` (not a new `*Thing`!)

*Everything in Go is passed by value, including pointers*. Pointers point to a memory address, which can be a shared value. But the pointer itself is still copied on function call.